# Can I ask a question about Drupal's third-party module that is not technical?

Tags: support, questions

Recently, I have started working on a [commerce payment module (Commerce Pasargad)](http://drupal.org/sandbox/mohamadaliakbari/1696668). Now I am looking for a way to put it in [Drupal Commerce Free Extensions](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/contrib/payment) page, but I didn't find any, so far.

Can I ask similar question on Drupal Answer website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it, Drupal Answers has no official affiliation with the Commerce Guys as far as I'm aware. The question would be (at best) too localised for this site.

There are [guidelines on drupalcommerce.org](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/contribute) detailing how you can get in touch with them to contribute code/modules/themes/etc. That would probably be the best place to start.